# powershell delete everything after character for every line in a file

Tags: powershell

I have a file full of lines like the one below, I would like to use powershell to delete everything after the first "<" in every line in the file

"10.0.0.1","pc1","Microsoft Windows Server 2008 SP2 <100%-accuracy> Microsoft Windows 7 SP0 - SP1, Windows Server 2008 SP1, or Windows 8 <100%-accuracy>"

"10.0.0.2","pc2","Microsoft Windows Server 2008 SP2 <100%-accuracy> Microsoft Windows 7 SP0 - SP1, Windows Server 2008 SP1, or Windows 8 <100%-accuracy>"

"10.0.0.3","pc3","Microsoft Windows Server 2008 SP2 <100%-accuracy> Microsoft Windows 7 SP0 - SP1, Windows Server 2008 SP1, or Windows 8 <100%-accuracy>"

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: I was going to do a get-content on the file, and then do a foreach $line in $file, but im not sure what to do about getting it to trim everything after the first "<"

Comment: You can do it like this: `$a="test<bla>";$a.Substring(0,$a.IndexOf("<"))` References: [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to truncate a line at a certain delimiter:

```
$line = '"10.0.0.1","pc1","Microsoft Windows Server 2008 SP2 <100%-accuracy> Microsoft Windows 7 SP0 - SP1, Windows Server 2008 SP1, or Windows 8 <100%-accuracy>"'

$linetruncated = $line.Substring(0,$line.IndexOf('<'))
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, it wont let me vote you up bcuz I do not have 15 rep, but this works!  this is what I ended up with                                     $a = get-content  =\scanreport.csv 
FOREACH ($line in $a)
{
$line.Substring(0,$line.IndexOf('<'))
}

Comment: You should be able to mark as answer.  Voting is for when there is more than one answer to decide which is a preferred one.  Thanks.  And thanks to Matt for helping my answer look better.