# Powershell - Delete Everything After a Delimiter - In Text files Found in Folder

Tags: powershell, directory

I would like to delete content from a bunch of text files.

In each text file  - Delete Everything After the  ******

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Desktop\Delete\*.txt"       # Folder Containing Text files  
$OutPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\"    

Get-Content c.txt | Where { $_ -notmatch "*****" } | Set-Content $OutPath
```

I have seen this [powershell delete everything after character for every line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842168/powershell-delete-everything-after-character-for-every-line-in-a-file)

I couldn't get it to work

I am a newbie with power shell do please forgive my code.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-Delimiter` parameter of `Get-Content` to do this pretty easily:

Disclaimer: not tested

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Desktop\Delete\*.txt"       # Folder Containing Text files  
$OutPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\"    

Foreach ($file in (Get-Childitem $path))
{
 (Get-Content $file.fullname -Delimiter '*****')[0] |
  Set-Content "$OutPath\$($file.name)"
 }
```

Comment: I can't believe it - 2 lines of code will save me hours of manual work. This is outstandingly awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a RegEx match by reading the whole file as one string, and using `-Replace`.

```
$OutPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\"
ForEach($File in Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Desktop\Delete\*.txt"){
    (Get-Content $File.FullName -Raw) -Replace "(?s)^(.*?\*{5,}).*", '$1' | Set-Content $OutPath + $File.Name
}
```

Pattern match explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/lC6fF8/1).

Comment: Thank you TMD, I am very afraid of regex - I will try it out :)