# Removing text before ',' for the entire txt file - recursively through the folder

Tags: powershell, edit, bulk

I have multiple files. Let's name them `File1`, `File2`, `File3` and so on. 
Each files has multiple lines in the format:

```
Some text,some more text,more text
```

I need to do the following:

1. In each line of each file, remove the first part of the text before the ",".
   So  "Some text,some more text,more text" should become "some more text,more text"
2. Prefix the respective file name to each line with a comma :
   "some more text,more text" - becomes "File1,some more text,more text"

I checked out a similar request here : [Powershell - Delete Everything After a Delimiter - In Text files Found in Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781809/powershell-delete-everything-after-a-delimiter-in-text-files-found-in-folder)

But still unable to get things rolling. This is what I tried for the first part of the request:

```
Foreach ($file in (Get-Childitem $path))
{
 (Get-Content $file.fullname -Delimiter ',')[1] |
  Set-Content "$OutPath\$($file.name)"
 }
```

This removes the text before the first "," and after the second "," - I need to keep all text after the first ",".

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to set your expectations. You should at least make an own attempt to get your task done and share the code here. Even if you don't have a good knowledge about Powershell.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, I did try this : 

Foreach ($file in (Get-Childitem $path))
{
 (Get-Content $file.fullname -Delimiter ',')[1] |
  Set-Content "$OutPath\$($file.name)"
 }
 
However, this gives me only the portion between the first and second ",". I need to get the entire string after the first "," @Thomas

Comment: @SiddhantKankani Please do not add additional information as comments. Update your question instead.

Comment: @Olaf - Sorry, updated now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [-split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-5.1) operator, on which you can specify how many parts you want in the result.

Something like this:

```
 $Path    = 'D:\Original'  # the path where the original files are
 $OutPath = 'D:\Updated'   # the path where the updated files should go

 # check if the output path exists. If not, create it
 if (!(Test-Path -Path $OutPath -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $OutPath -ItemType Directory
 }

 foreach ($file in (Get-Childitem -Path $path -File)) { 
    (Get-Content $file.FullName) | ForEach-Object {
        # the $_ automatic variable represents one line for each iteration.

        # output the updated line. The cleanest way I think is to use the -f Format operator.
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#format-operator--f
        '{0},{1}' -f $file.Name, ($_ -split ',', 2)[-1] 
    } |
    Set-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $OutPath -ChildPath $file.Name)
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the quick help. 

I needed the file name to be added without the extension, so used $file.Basename. 

Thanks :-)

Comment: You could have mentioned that in your question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to use regex and the `-replace` operator:

```
Foreach ($file in (Get-Childitem $path)) {
    $Content = Get-Content -Path $file.fullname
    $NewContent = 
    foreach ($line in $Content) {
        $line -replace '^.*?(?=,)', $file.BaseName
    }
    $NewContent | Out-File -FilePath "$OutPath\$($file.name)"
}
```